# Automorphisms of an infinite graph built from a finite motif

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we have a lattice $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for which we choose some fundamental domain $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic to a closed ball.  Translates of $D$ by distinct elements of $L$ intersect at most on their boundaries.

Suppose we have a finite graph $G_0$ embedded in $D$ with some vertices,  but no edges, lying on the boundary.  We construct an infinite graph $G$ as a union of all the translates of $G_0$ by elements of $L$, identifying vertices that belong to different translates when their positions in the embedding coincide.  We assume that $G$ is connected.

If we write $E(G_0)$ and $E(G)$ for the set of edges of these graphs, there is an obvious map $c:E(G)\to E(G_0)$ which amounts to a colouring of the edges of $G$ with $|E(G_0)|$ colours, inherited from the translates of $G_0$.

My question is, can $G$ have an automorphism $\phi: E(G)\to E(G)$ that does *not* simply permute the edge colouring?  Or must there *always* be a permutation $\rho_{\phi}: E(G_0) \to E(G_0)$ such that $c(\phi(e))=\rho_{\phi}(c(e))$ for every $e \in E(G)$?

Obviously $G$ will always have an infinite subgroup of automorphisms arising from $L$ for which $\rho_{\phi}$ is the identity.  And it's easy to construct examples with other automorphisms that simply permute the edge colouring:

[image: Graphene graph]

To be clear, although we have an embedding of $G$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I am not restricting the question to automorphisms that arise from homeomorphisms $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$; any graph automorphism of $G$ counts.